# What are Death's stats for the “Chess with death” haunt in Betrayal at the House on the Hill?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

In the "Chess with death" haunt, death appears in a room and starts a chess game with the players. If a player isn't in the room to take their turn when death's turn rolls around, the players lose the game. However, if one of the non-traitor players is in the room, they get to play a game of chess with death.

death and the players must make a knowledge roll against each-other, death must win the roll or the traitor loses the game. if the player loses, all players (including the loser) take a penalty, usually stat-lowering effects.

There are holy symbols around that players can destroy to make death perform worse on their rolls. There are 4 symbols that the players can destroy. each destroyed symbol will subtract 1 or 2 dice from death's rolls.

The thing that puzzled my players is that there seemed to be no skills or stats for death in the traitor's tome, as confirmed by every player at the table. We assumed that Death had perfect 8 for every stat, but there are haunts where some creatures get up to 12.

What are Death's stats tor the "Chess With Death" haunt in the game Betrayal at the House on the Hill?

Comment: Monsters only have the traits that the tome says they have. Lots of monsters don't have sanity, or don't have strength, or don't have intelligence, etc.

Comment: @GendoIkari death kind of needs a knowledge start to play chess, though .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you're referring to Haunt 37, titled Checkmate

As per the [REVISED Traitor's Manual](http://www.wizards.com/avalonhill/rules/BHH_TraitorRev_120105.pdf), Death has a Knowledge of 8 (and it cheats). It has no other stats, and cannot be attacked by any means. As per the (revised) Survivor's Handbook, Each Holy Seal token removes one die (two in 3- or 4-player games) from all subsequent knowledge rolls by Death. (in a 5-player game, the effective minimum knowledge for Death is 3, while in smaller games, it is possible for Death to be forced to take a 0 on the roll).